# python : object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json

I am getting the following error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

with the following code

```
request = data[0]["body"]
```

Where as following works fine :

```
request = None
request = data[0]["body"]
```

Can someone please explain the behavior?

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: I doubt that the extra line will make any difference since it does not do any change to `data`.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, `data` or the first index of `data` has the value of None. You will get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` when you try and use indexes `[]` on `None` (or in your case a variable with a value of None). The scenario you described doesn't provide enough context to suggest when this is occurring, however.